# How to download a .exe file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, middleware

I try to find a way to make download a .exe file to the clients which request the route /download in my middleware.

I tried something like it:

`if (context.Request.Path == "/download")
    context.Response.Redirect("exe/myfile.exe");`

Actually, we can't redirect to the file as a StaticFile because .Net Core seems to not allow .exe files as static files.

Is it at least possible to init a download from a middleware ? If yes, how can I do it ?
Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you zip you .exe file, and then download de zip file instead.

Comment: No I absolutely have to make download a .exe file